# how to know what is height and width of container while using FractionallySizedBox in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created this demo for explaining wht i want to..

its simple, i want to create a container, which can be wrapped by any SizedBox and than i want to know what is height and width of this container holds..

container's text i want to display height and width of container

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            heightFactor: 0.3,
            widthFactor: 0.3,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Center(
                  child: Text('My height is 400 and width is 400')),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```